# How to update many fields at once in mongoDB PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'd like to do an update query in mongo in a php page to update many fields at once, i tryed updateOne in this way:

```
$collection->updateOne(
    ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($data['_id'])],
    ['$set' => ['name' => $data['name']]],
    ['$set' => ['owner' => $data['owner']]]
);
```

but doesn't work

Right now I made it working in two separate queries

```
$collection->updateOne(
    ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($data['_id'])],
    ['$set' => ['name' => $data['name']]]
);
}

$collection->updateOne(
    ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($data['_id'])],
    ['$set' => ['owner' => $data['owner']]]
);
}
```

How can i do this in a single query??

Comment: `['$set' => ['name' => $data['name'], 'name' => $data['name'] ]]` All in the documentation for [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Comment: it works thanks bro